# trying to retrieve element from an OrderedCollection

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, squeak, gnu-smalltalk

I am using `pharo`. I have a `Car` class which has a `speed` variable and the class side method `withSpeed: aSpeed` which sets `speed := aSpeed.`

I am trying the following test in the playground.

```
car := Car withSpeed: 20.
cars := OrderedCollection new.
cars add: car.
```

Now, I have a `car` inside `cars` collection.

I want to get the car which has `speed = 20` I am trying the following code, but it gives me error:

```
result := cars select: [ :each | each withSpeed: 20. ].
```

Any idea what is going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that your `Car` has an accessor for `speed`, you simply can do

```
result := cars select: [ :each | each speed = 20. ].
```

That gets you all cars that have the speed `20`. If you only want one, you should use `detect:`

```
myCar := cars detect: [ :each | each speed = 20. ].
```

---

Accessors for instance variables (here `speed`) typically look like

```
Car>>speed
    ^ speed
```

and

```
Car>>speed: anObject
    speed := anObject.
```

Comment: possibly use `#detect:ifNone:` to catch the case where no such element is in the collection.

Comment: Yes, that's even better. Thanks Max

Answer (score 4):

Your error is probably due to the fact that `#withSpeed` is defined on the class-side, but you are sending it to instances. This is a common trap for new users and is nicely clarified in [Pharo By Example](http://pharobyexample.org/) (Section 5.3).

Although that may not be the problem at all because your description of the error is way too vague. Going forward, copy the debugger window title and any relevant part of the call chain and you'll get better answers!